# next-auth signIn with google provider is not working within form

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I am working with nextjs with next-auth for google oauth. I made a custom signin page keeping the component which would launch the google oauth page within a form

/auth/signin.jsx

```
const signIn = ({providers}) => {
  return (
                ...
                <form className="flex flex-col space-y-1 mt-6">
                ...                
                {Object.values(providers).map((provider) =>(
                  <div key={provider.name}>
                    <button className="p-3 bg-blue-500 rounded-lg text-white"
                      onClick={() => SignIntoProviders(provider.id)}
                    >
                      Login with {provider.name}
                    </button>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </form>
              ...
   )
}
```

providers is an object I get using getProviders() from next-auth

The google oauth works when *onClick={() => SignIntoProviders(provider.id)}* is placed outside the form. However when kept within the form, I get "http://localhost:3000/auth/signin?". Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the game (and hopefully this is no longer an issue for you), but I'd guess that this is a case of the form submit (and subsequent POST) interfering with the `onClick` handler you've registered. The first button within a form gets treated as a `submit` type, unless explicitly set otherwise. You could set the button to explicitly not be a submit button (e.g. `<button type='button'>`), but that will leave the other form submission behavior (e.g. submitting when the user hits Enter) in place, which could result in a user getting that same error screen.

Instead, overriding the form submission handler can ensure you're only performing the requests you intend to. If you don't want to allow the default form submission behavior, you could override the default `onSubmit` event for the form to something like:

```js
<form 
  onSubmit={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); return false; } 
  className="flex flex-col space-y-1 mt-6"
>
```

If you do want to keep the default form submission behavior, you could also remove the click handler from your button directly, and instead add `SignIntoProviders(provider.id)` into the `onSubmit` listener from above, e.g.

```js
<form 
  onSubmit={(e) => { 
    SignIntoProviders(provider.id);
    e.preventDefault(); 
    return false; 
  } 
  className="flex flex-col space-y-1 mt-6"
>
```